# How do I install libgit2 on OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, python

I'm trying to install [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2) on OSX, and I keep running into issues. Ultimately I'm trying to get [pygit2](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2) installed, which fails because it doesn't recognize libgit2 being installed.

libgit2's instructions are the following according to their github page:

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. 
$ cmake --build .
```

They then say that in order to build the universal binary for OSX, you can use the following when configuring:

```
-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="i386;x86_64"
```

To me that means do the following:

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="i386;x86_64"
$ cmake --build .
```

However, that doesn't appear to work. I still have pygit2 bomb out when I try and install it through pip.

```
$ pip install pygit2
```

This is the error I get:

```
In file included from src/pygit2.c:32:

include/pygit2/types.h:60: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘git_diff_list’

src/pygit2.c: In function ‘moduleinit’:

src/pygit2.c:231: error: ‘GIT_STATUS_CURRENT’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/pygit2.c:231: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

src/pygit2.c:231: error: for each function it appears in.)

*snip*

Command /Users/HOMEDIR/VIRTUALENVPATH/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/HOMEDIR/VIRTUALENVPATH/build/pygit2/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/3v/7q7kyp3x4js3j0hvhmfkt6fw0000gn/T/pip-Sbr_Q3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/HOMEDIR/VIRTUALENVPATH/bin/../include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/HOMEDIR/VIRTUALENVPATH/build/pygit2
```

Has anyone been through this rodeo before and can help out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I coul not install `pygit2` using `pip`. However, it worked fine using the latest version available on Github:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/libgit2/pygit2.git
$ cd pygit2
$ python setup.py install
```

The problem here I think is that you're trying to use a [two month old `pygit2` release](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/commit/1148c5d73bbe44d96d5ca084145fd157c2748750) with the cutting edge version of `libgit2`. If using `pip` is an absolute necessity, you should try installing an older version of `libgit2` too (like [this one](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/17b06f4d47bfd9fae8073c85d71751df94e50050)).

You only have to use the `-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="i386;x86_64"` flag if you're targeting "old" Macs without 64 bits capable processors (before Core 2 x, with Snow Leopard or older).

You should also run

```
$ cmake --build . --target install
```

after your

```
$ cmake --build .
```

command. Without this, `libgit2` headers (`*.h`) and libraries (`*.dylib`) will not be installed in your `/usr/local/{include,lib}` directories and will not be available to others softwares (hence your compilations errors).